# top menu navigation items in Materialize framework

Tags: css, materialize

I'm evaluating materializecss web framework to use as front-end for a java-based web project I'm working on. I was following the examples in http://materializecss.com/navbar.html, I realise that the navigation for these examples are side-menus but there's no top menu item nav should I not want side navigation in my site (atleast none I've come across). Please help.

Comment: Hm, not sure what you mean by 'top menu navigation'?

Comment: @ sinisake if you go to https://getmdl.io/, the menu at the top of the page: About | Getting Started | and so forth. if you go to the "Components page", it has a top and side menu for example, check: https://getmdl.io/components/index.html. Hope this is clear

Comment: The css frameworks at http://materializecss.com (in your question) and https://getmdl.io (in your comment), while both based on the design principles of Google's Material Design, are **two different implementations**. So what works in one isn't necessarily going to work in the other.